# Remove white gaps which appear when the local tile map is zoom in-out in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, zoom, mapping

I am using QGIS with local XYZ layer. When I zoom in, zoom out and move the map the layers load slowly. First there is white gaps int the edges, then the map loads and the gaps close. On the other hand when I use other platforms like GoogleMaps, when you zoom in or zoom out they blur the map first the they load the map. This way there is a smoother look and you don't see any white gaps while loading the map.

Is there any way that I can implement this to my QGIS application?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to implement this in QGIS.

This is a function of web display frameworks, like Leaflet and OpenLayers. They keep the old tiles until new ones are loaded.

This is not functionality in QGIS, as it is primarily used for local data.

QGIS does store a local cache for XYZ layers so if it is an area you are using all the time the tiles will be stored locally, and you should see these gaps less often.